# Swift - Problems with layout

Tags: xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I have a Universal application in Swift 2.0 developed in XCode 7.

On the storyboard simulated metrics, I have the 'size' set to 'iPhone 4.7-inch'.

When I run the application on my device (iPhone 5s), none of the labels are aligned and the toolbar is out of view. -This is also the case when I run using the iPad device in XCodes simulator.

Image of what the view controller contains ...

[image]

From the snippet above, when I run this VC on my iPhone there is no margin on the right side, and the toolbar is cropped off.

Can anyone advise how I can make a universal application show all the content in the VC, on all devices. Or how I would simply show the toolbar ...

Comment: How are your constraints at this controller you showed? It is possible that some constraints are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what auto layout (*constraints*) is for.

> On the storyboard simulated metrics, I have the 'size' set to 'iPhone 4.7-inch'.

That's irrelevant, and indeed misleading, since in means that only on the iPhone 4.7-inch will your app look like the storyboard design — unless you use auto layout.

iPhones come in many screen sizes. Basically, you have no way of knowing, as you design, *what* the screen size will actually be! Auto layout is the solution. Auto layout allows your interface elements to adjust *automatically* as the app launches on a particular size screen. iPads can serve as an extension of this — i.e., just an even larger size screen — or you can even use *conditional constraints* to make the interface quite different on the iPad from the iPhone, if desired - all designed in a single storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using auto layout and auto constraint. You could deactivate this in opening the storyboard, open up right panel , go to "show the file inspector" section and under Interface Builder Document uncheck auto layout and auto constraint

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FN5X.png)

Select your item view, go into "Show the size inspector" and there you can set your autoresizing for all devices